# Wechat Miniprogram debug page's stack

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need to see the navigation flow between my pages in wechat miniprogram. I have searched the net and have not seen how I can see the pages that are in the stack.

**My question is:**

Is it possible to debug the page stack in wechat miniprogram from the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method of "getCurrentPages()" when you need.
When the page stack change, the return data of method will not change.You must use it again to get the lastest data.

Otherwise, you can use the parameter of "debug" in "app.json".
With opening it, when the page stack change you can see it in the console tool.

Comment: Your answer worked at the moment, without a doubt a +1. Could you explain to me exactly how to specify the debug parameter in the project.config.json file? Thanks

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry about the error.It's "app.json" in the root of program instead of "project.config.json".For more infomation：https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/reference/configuration/app.html#debug